# how to make button with close icon in right corner using react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

in reactjs [image]how to make button with close icon in right corner using react js. in my below code when i run the page  i want to  make button with close icon in right corner.when i click cross icon then button is closed.

How can we do that.anyone please help me out.i am stuck on that.its very thankful.

how can we do that this type button which i have posted i want to make this type when i run the page using reactjs .anyone know about that using reactjs

check here in my code.in here i wan to make cross icon with right corner
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-ddpf9?file=/src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger"
          // onClick={() => {
          //   if (window.confirm("Delete the item?")) {
          //     let removeToCollection = this.removeToCollection.bind(this, 121);
          //     removeToCollection();
          //   }
          // }}
        >
          Warning Meaasge with close option
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  removeToCollection(key, e) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Anyone plz help me out . its very thankful i am stuck on that

Comment: Are you using bootstrap react module of just js library file?

Comment: yes we can use bootstrap npm packages

Comment: how can we make this type which i have posted image is there any idea using reactjs can u plz check here n my code https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-ddpf9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-ddpf9?file=/src/index.js in here my code  i want to add only cross icon

Comment: Have a look here - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/. The cross icon you can easily style and place on the right

Comment: yes thanks i already try but i not able to implement in my code https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-ddpf9?file=/src/index.js when i try make show error

Comment: can u help me out in my code and show me something .its very thankful

Comment: Have a look here - https://jsfiddle.net/sqfhkdcy/

Comment: Thanks for this .but don't need after click on button modal open

Comment: i want in my code https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-ddpf9?file=/src/index.js:204-272 in here on the place of button i want to open direct modal

Comment: is it possible ??@ zam abdul

Comment: is its possible on the place of button model is show

Comment: i want to make direct open model without onclick if is it possible ?? or is it possible in button we can make right corner cross icon ?? can u help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a custom `Modal` component and injected it in `App` component.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-example1-yz2mez?file=index.js

**Note**:- You can replace the html mark up using bootstrap structure if you need to. If you want to open the dialog once closed, you can uncomment the `p` tag i the root component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div and style accordingly, if you want to perform a specific function on onClick, then you can use **event.target.id** .
I have used the state to show and hide button.

Sample Code -  https://codesandbox.io/s/close-icon-at-top-5czwf?file=/src/index.js